# How can I open the "Advanced Sharing Settings" section of the Network and Sharing section

Tags: c#, networking, windows-10

Using the C# code below, I can open the "Network and Sharing Center" control panel. But I'd like to go one level deeper, and open the "Advanced Sharing Settings" window. Can anyone help?

PS. I found this MS [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741(v=vs.85).aspx#NetworkAndSharingCenter) that got me as far as I did.

```
var cplPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "control.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cplPath, "/name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the end:

> /page Advanced

Like this:

```
var cplPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "control.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cplPath, "/name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter /page Advanced");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!